# Regarding with Javascript array shuffle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

recently I have read tutorial from some of the web page about Javascript function that shuffles array. but some portion of the code I didn't understood completely.
for ex:here is [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2m5q3d2j/6/)

here i dont understand this code part

```
this[i] = this[j] + (this[j] = this[i],0);
```

what does it means `(this[j] = this[i],0);`
?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a kinda "clever" way to exchange two array elements. Don't use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any expression with commas, *all expressions are executed* and the **last** *expression is returned*.

```
var a = (1+1, 2+2, 3+3);
// a = 6
```

For the case above:

```
this[i] = this[j] + (this[j] = this[i], 0);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var temp = this[j];
this[j] = this[i];
this[i] = temp + 0;
```

The temp is automatically handled, because left-side (`this[j]`) is evaluated first.

[More details](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6524-the-confusing-comma-in-javascript.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i did't understand the meaning of  'temp + 0;'

Comment: `(this[j] = this[i], 0)` expression evaluates `this[j] = this[i]` and `0`, and returns only the right-most expression (`0`). The `0` comes from there, and `temp` comes from `this[j]`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now i understood!

Answer (score 3):

The code is just doing a 1-line swap.

You're familiar with the standard swap, correct?

A = 6, B = 10

X = A

A = B

B = X

now B = 6, and A = 10

Take a look at your tutorial code

`this[i] = this[j] + (...)` means that the assignment will not take place right away. Instead, the parenthetical must be calculated first. However, the browser will temporarily make a note of the value of `this[j]`, essentially copying it to X.

`(this[j] = this[i],0)` can now be calculated, but what does the parenthesis return to be added to the outside `this[j]`? The 0! So inside the parenthesis, the second step of the swap took place, and 0 is added to the temporary X!

Now the calculation becomes `this[i] = this[j] + 0`. The third step of swap!